# Iterate over R dataframe objects and add a column

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, object, iteration

I have a number of dataframes as R objects named with a prefix and a number. Each dataframe has same column names and numbers as row names.

I am trying to add a column based on the object iteration. I am trying the following:

```
x <- 1
repeat{
get(paste0('prefix', x))$iteration <- x-1
x = x + 1
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Could you explain why this does not work and suggest a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the values of objects that starts with 'prefix' followed by any digits into a `list` ('lst1'), then use `Map` to create a new column by subtracting 1 from the numeric part of the object name ('v1'), use `list2env` to reflect the changes in the original objects in global env

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^prefix\\d+$'))
v1 <- as.numeric(sub("prefix", "", names(lst1))) -1
lst1 <- Map(cbind, lst1, iteration = v1)
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```